# Armature rigging seems fine in Edit mode, but messed up in Pose and Object mode

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints

I'm not sure what is causing this but have a feeling it is simple. My armature rig is fine in Edit mode, but changing to Object or Pose mode flicks and sticks the right leg to the left. Anyone know what may cause this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: it might simply be a pose, but did you aplied automatic weighting for combining mesh and bone system ?.

Comment: not yet. I'm trying to make sure the rig is in order before I apply weight.

Answer (score 1):

Go into pose mode. Press "A" a couple times until your entire armature is selected. Press Alt+G, Alt+S, and Alt+R until the bones are back where they belong.

Comment: I've tried that. It isn't a bone positioning issue but seems to be a constraint issue. Just not sure why it is doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I forgot to duplicate and copy the IK bone I had set hidden.